# App is crashes after successfully upload of 100+ images and then opening camera

Tags: ios, xcode, image-uploading, ipad-mini

App is crashes after successfully upload of 100+ images and opening camera. Tested application leaks with leak instrument but there is no leaks at all.

Is there any tool or solution which tell us where the problem exactly is, in which files etc..

I am displaying all the 100+ images in tableview cell.

Comment: Ok and what are we supposed to do with the (lack of) information you have supplied? You will _at least_ need to show us some code

Comment: are you image in caching?

Comment: the same thing happened to me on iPhone 4s . But my app works perfectly fine on other newer iPhones. On referring some other posts here i got to know that this is because of the relatively old hardware present in 4s

Comment: With the information you give us, the best advice I can give is that you need to find the cause of the problem and fix it.

Comment: @Shai, Sorry for inconvenience, is there any tool besides leak instrument which identify the file and point where leaks happen.

Comment: Its happens because of memory leak. Clear your cache, delete stored images into variables, etc... using your code.

Comment: You can use instruments to detect any memory leaks... Product->build for->profiling

Comment: Thanks @V.J. you are right we need to clear the cache and  stored image object. Here I am removing each object of image after successful upload of  it from array.